# removing an object from a class holding objects

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, typeerror

How can I remove an object from a class holding objects?

The question sounds a bit confusing. Basically, I have a character class which has an inventory - a list of item objects. One of my methods in the character class involves removing an item from the inventory. I know in order to do that I just have to do (listname).remove(item), however I run into errors. I keep getting **"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"** if I try something such as

player1.removeInventory(inv[0])
 where inv is a list of objects.

Here are my classes for items and inventory:

**Item**

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, itemType, value):
        self.__itemType = itemType
        self.__value = value
```

**To string for item**

```
def __str__(self):
    out = ""
    out += "\nType: " + self.__itemType
    out += "\nValue: " + str(self.__value)
    return out
```

**INVENTORY CLASS**

```
class Inventory(object):   #Aggregation from item
    def __init__(self, items):
    self.__items = items  #A list of items
```

**To string for inventory**

```
def __str__(self):
    out = ""
    out += "\nItems: "
    for x in self.__items:
        out += str(x)
    return out
```

The inventory is an argument in the class for a character.

**Character Class**

```
class Player(object): #Aggregation from Inventory
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, playerClass, HP, ATK, DEF, inventory, gold = 0, level = 1, defending = False):
    self.__level = level
    self.__name = name
    self.__age = age
    self.__gender = gender
    self.__playerClass = playerClass
    self.__HP = HP
    self.__ATK = ATK
    self.__DEF = DEF
    self.__inventory = inventory ##list of items...###
    self.__gold = gold
    self.__defending = defending
```

**getting the inventory with a property**

```
@property
def inventory(self):
    number = 1
    out = ""
    for item in self.__inventory:
        out += str(item)
        number +=1
    return out
```

**Method to remove an item**

```
@inventory.setter
def removeInventory(self, item):
    self.__inventory.remove(item)
```

**The code I've tried running**

```
i1 = Item("Health potion", 1)
i2 = Item("Health potion", 1)
inv = [i1,i2]
player1 = Player("Brandon",19,"Male","Wizard", 100, 15, 10, inv, 200)
print(player1.inventory)
player1.removeInventory(inv[0])
print(player1.inventory)
```

Comment: this is not enough code to reproduce your error.  for example, you do not include where you set `self.__inventory`.

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me, but I had to remove the @inventory.setter line to avoid "NameError: name 'inventory' is not defined". The error must be there, then!

Comment: @jblasco dont I need a setter property to use it? Although the program worked for me as well after removing that line...

Comment: I am no expert in setters, but no, you don't need them, they are just convenient ways of changing the value of some property. But you need to name them exactly the same, see http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php . There, you can see that you'd need to change the name removeInventory( for inventory( for the setter to be properly used. I wouldn't do it, though, because I'm sure you just want to add and remove things, so normal methods within your class will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `property`, and a `setter` function in this property, it will be called whenever one does an assignement to that property.
That means your

```
@inventory.setter
def removeInventory(self, item):
    self.__inventory.remove(item)
```

Method will actually be called when there is code like: `(character).inventory = item` - 
which is mostly certain NOT what you want (the given item would be removed instead of added to the inventory - or become the inventory)

Instead, to do call it as you want, with `player1.removeInventory(inv[0])`, just leave the method undecorated, without the `@property.(...)` decorator.